# Why do i need www. and non www in /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, hosts

Why for some website to get blocked by the /etc/hosts file I need the www version and the non www version. While for others the non www version in enough ?

on `surviv.io` I need both 'versions':

```
0.0.0.0    surviv.io
0.0.0.0    www.surviv.io
```

while for some others like `stallman.org`, the non www version in enough.

```
0.0.0.0    stallman.org
```

My question as said on top in why is it like that ?

Answer (score 2):

You need both version because not every site uses/requires a `www` cname.  You are also mistaken when you reference stallman.org.

If you add only:

```
0.0.0.0     stallman.org
```

to your `/etc/hosts` file you will still be able to browse to `www.stallman.org`

Most sites today don't require the `www` cname but still have it as an option so you need to block both:

```
0.0.0.0     stallman.org 
0.0.0.0     www.stallman.org
```

---

Also using your `/etc/hosts` file is not the most efficient way to block websites, you should probably look into applications designed for this instead.